# How to add Move to OneNote 2013 button to the Ribbon in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I started a new job recently.  My computer at the office has Office 2010 installed.  However, I've also installed my personal license of Office 365, giving me "access" (har har) to the 2013 versions of the programs.  I've done this on previous work computers because I strongly prefer OneNote and Excel 2013 to the previous versions.

Anyway, Outlook 2010 has a "OneNote" button in the "Move" category of the Home tab.  Clicking it, however, attempts to send a note to OneNote 2010 (which hasn't been set up).  I'm trying to figure out how to modify this button, or add a new button altogether, that would instead trigger a note to be created in OneNote 2013.

In short, how do you add a "Move to OneNote 2013" button in Outlook 2010?

Comment: Can you uninstall OneNote 2010?  In the end you are asking about something that is not intended and likely an edge case when it comes to configuration of Outlook.

Comment: @Ramhound - I uninstalled OneNote 2010 and with it the Move button disappeared altogether.  I couldn't figure out how to install the button for 2013.  I seem to recall this worked without a problem at my old job.  However, I tried to see if I could use Outlook 2013 instead of 2010, and my work account opened up in there without issue, and of course Outlook 2013 has the button for OneNote 2013.  In other words, I'm done with 2010 completely.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Go to default programs
2. Find Microsoft OneNote 2013
3. Click "Set this program as default"

This answer is good when you have two OneNote's installed.